# Can I stop text pushing forward the following text in batch?

Tags: variables, batch-file, text, cmd

I want to place a variable before text on the same line without pushing the text forward when the variable changes its amount of characters.

Eg.

```
@echo off
set var=1
:start
cls
echo Variable: %var%           'Text'
echo                       '    '
pause >nul
set /a var= %var% * 10
goto start
```

Every time the variable expands the text shifts to the right, is it possible to keep the text in the same place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set your variable to a known lenght (adding spaces to it and cutting at a fixed length

```
@echo off
set "spaces=                "
set var=1
:start
cls
set var=%var%%spaces%
set var=%var:~0,15%
echo Variable: %var%'Text'
echo           %spaces:~0,15%'    '
pause >nul
set /a var= %var% * 10
goto start
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET "string=                 Text"
SET /a var=1

:loop
FOR /l %%a IN (1,1,30) DO IF "!var:~%%a,1!"=="" SET "newstr=%var%!string:~%%a!"&GOTO foundlen
:foundlen
ECHO %newstr%

SET /a var*=10
IF %var% gtr 0 GOTO loop
GOTO :EOF
```

Assumes the length of `var` is less than 30.

Varies `%%a` until `%%a` is the length of the prefix string and then strings the prefix to the other string, removing `%%a` characters.

If the prefix string `var` may be empty, then

```
set "newstr=%string%"
if defined var for /l ...
```

I chose to force the loop to terminate by exploiting the 31-bit nature of integer mathematics in `cmd` - if the number grows >2**31 then it may appear negative. This is simply a way to terminate the loop rather than explicitly checking that it has the maximum allowable length.